# Rails migration problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it a good practice to insert new records through migration?Recently, I got a strange error when rerunning local migrations from scratch. It throws an errors like this(Eg: Product model, Cost column):

> `undefined method 'cost=' for #<Product:0x10f60f4b8>`

Migration:

```
class AddNewProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    product1 = Product.new
    product1.cost = 10
    ....
    product1.save!
  end
end
```

Column **cost** was added in a migration previously:

```
Class AddCosttoProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def self.up
      add_column :product, :cost, :integer, :default => 0, :null => false   
    end

    def self.down
      remove_column product, :cost
    end
end
```

Any hint on why it happens?

Comment: What version of rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already ran the previous migration (to add `cost` field), try resetting column information before you add records.

```
class AddNewProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Product.reset_column_information
    product1 = Product.new
    product1.cost = 10
    ....
    product1.save!
  end
end
```